# What is a validationQuery with respect to databases and JNDI?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, sybase, jndi

I seem to be having the same exact problem as the poster of [this original SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591420/sql-anywhere-11-jz0c0-connection-is-already-closed).

The problem is, he answered his own question with the following comment:

> I solved my problem, I added a validationQuery to my JNDI datasource.

Unfortunately, that doesn't mean anything to me, and doesn't help me solve my problem. So I ask: what is a "`validationQuery`" with respect to my database (Sybase) and the JNDI entry used to hold the server lookup info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The validation query is a query run by the data source to validate that a `Connection` is still open before returning it.  Here's Tomcat's [definition of a validation query](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources); scroll down to the middle of section "4. Configure Tomcat's Resource Factory", looking for the "validationQuery" attribute.

**EDIT**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449040/1707091), if the validation query fails, no error is thrown; the bad/closed connection is dropped and another connection is created to replace it.

Comment: Thanks @rgettman (+1) - so it's a query that I configure Sybase (the data source) to run prior to returning a connection. I assume it throws an exception that I can catch, or returns some error-value that I can use on the app-side to determine that a connection isn't available, and that I need to try again? Thanks again!

Comment: And another thing: that article doesn't explain what happens when a connection isn't available? Throws an error?

Answer (score 2):

It has no relevance to JNDI, but JDBC datasources.

The validation query is used to validate connections from the datasource connection pool, 
before those are handed-off to the clients. Usually these are low impact query such as 
"SELECT 1..." or "SELECT SYSDATE..."

Comment: Thanks @orid (+1) - please see my question under rgettman's answer - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is a query to test if DB connection works fine. Some sort of ping on the app-server level.

In the original question periodic pinging of the DB keeps the connection opened.

Comment: Thanks @Funtik (+1) - please see my question under rgettman's answer - I have the same question for you!