# SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S connection abort: recv failed

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis

I have a problem with the connection to the database, after a period of inactivity in the application, I return to enter and send me the following error

```
01-08-2014 04:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet springapp lanzó excepción
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

and this is my oracle data source

```
<!-- Load properties with PlaceHolder -->
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/properties/*.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"    value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url"                value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username"           value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password"           value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <!-- aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* *..Service.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice"/ -->
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* cl.bbr.proceso.maestro.proceso.ProcesoMaestro.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get','is','select' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="select*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="noTxAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

EDIT 05/08/2014
DATABASE : ORACLE 11G
SPRING VERSION : 3.0
TOMCAT 6.0

hopefully you can help me thanks.

Comment: Could you specify your web server, db engine, spring version please?

Comment: Try to add <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 from dual" /> <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" /> to your datasource bean. This will check connection before every request.

Comment: thanks for the time it has worked for me, could you explain me better this code does? or where I can find documentation for this. Thanks again, I post it as a response to indicate that it is correct. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this lines to dataSource bean solved the problem:

```
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 from dual" /> 
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
```

About validation query you can read in the answer for this question: [What is a validationQuery with respect to databases and JNDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393954/what-is-a-validationquery-with-respect-to-databases-and-jndi)

"testOnBorrow" means that before every query execution validationQuery will be executed.