# I get java.sql.SQLException: The connection does not exist

Tags: java, sql, db2-400

I have this error when I want to make a query, everything works fine in my application until 8 pm but at 3 am when I make a query to the base it responds that the connection does not exist, besides I can not replicate the error in the development environment

```
2017-04-09 20:23:01 | 6185 | 76 | LogSystemBS | println  >> finalizo proceso 
de ejecucion de proceso con id= 4 con intentos= 1
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> en la funcion 
configurarFabrica 7887
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> en la fabrica del:  fabricaSistemaSeguros
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> fecha 10/04/2017
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> nueva fecha 20170410
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> ****** 
parametros enviados a entorno*****
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> NPE--->048400000083960104217047
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> fecha--->20170410
2017-04-10 03:50:41 | 6185 | 5890 | LogSystemBS | println  >> aviso--->0
java.sql.SQLException: The connection does not exist.
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:382)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.checkOpen(AS400JDBCConnection.java:387)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.send(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2239)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.close(AS400JDBCStatement.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:168)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:168)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.impl.jdbcbasico.ServicioJDBCResultSet.ejecutar(ServicioJDBCResultSet.java:82)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.Servicio.invocar(Servicio.java:150)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.FabricaServicios.operacion(FabricaServicios.java:410)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.FabricaServicios.obtenerDatos(FabricaServicios.java:357)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.remoto.Escuchador.obtenerResultados(Escuchador.java:42)
at com.j2ee.sv.j2entorno.escuchador.servlets.http.OperacionesEscuchador$2.operacion(OperacionesEscuchador.java:61)
at com.j2ee.sv.j2entorno.escuchador.servlets.http.EscuchadorHTTPEntorno.doPost(EscuchadorHTTPEntorno.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.impl.jdbcbasico.ServicioJDBCResultSet.ejecutar(ServicioJDBCResultSet.java:87)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.Servicio.invocar(Servicio.java:150)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.FabricaServicios.operacion(FabricaServicios.java:410)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.FabricaServicios.obtenerDatos(FabricaServicios.java:357)
at com.hsbc.sv.desarrollo.interconexion.remoto.Escuchador.obtenerResultados(Escuchador.java:42)
at com.j2ee.sv.j2entorno.escuchador.servlets.http.OperacionesEscuchador$2.operacion(OperacionesEscuchador.java:61)
at com.j2ee.sv.j2entorno.escuchador.servlets.http.EscuchadorHTTPEntorno.doPost(EscuchadorHTTPEntorno.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? If yes, your server is likely killing idle connections (or database server was rebooted). Did you configure a validation query for the connection pool, so it can check for that before giving the connection to you webapp? If not, do so.

Comment: `<Resource
  name="jdbc/DB2_IBS_BSV"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="*******"
  password="******"
                  driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
  url="jdbc:as400://SV4013CB/"
  maxActive="50"
  maxIdle="30"
/>`

Comment: try adding `testOnBorrow="true"`    I use also : `removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"`

Comment: So I was right: No [**validation query**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15393954/5221149). So let me repeat: *Configure one!*

Comment: `<Resource
  name="jdbc/DB2_IBS_BSV"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="******"
  password="******"
  driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
  url="jdbc:as400://SV4013CB/"
  maxActive="50"
  maxIdle="20"
  validationQuery=”SELECT CURRENT DATE FROM sysibm.sysdummy1”
  testOnBorrow="true"
  removeAbandoned="true" 
  removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
  logAbandoned="true"
/>` How can I test my changes without waiting so long?

Comment: carrefull, I use org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool and you seem to be using Apache common DBCP, so perhaps the option are slightly different like  removeAbandoned - > removeAbandonedOnBorrow , see [common DBCP options](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).   To try before the timeout,  you can kill the QZDASOINIT connection job on the IBM i side

Comment: I don't know, but what happens when subsystems are taken down for backups? Are any subsystems taken down for backups?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help, it works just adding `validationQuery=”SELECT CURRENT DATE FROM sysibm.sysdummy1”` to my context.xml